# Perl numbers don't equal each other but appear the same when printed to STDOUT

Tags: perl, operators

I am reading in numbers from two different data files, and doing some basic math on them (adding them together to get a total for one file, and taking the absolute value for the other file).

When I try to compare them with the == operator, they don't appear equal! But I don't get any error messages about how the variables aren't numbers, or anything like that. I think I'm missing something easy, but I've been banging my head against a wall.

```
my $vendor_total = 0;
            
print "hash total: ", $our_payments{$id}{'total'}, "\n\n";

my $our_total = abs($our_payments{$id}{'total'});
print "our total: $our_total\n";
            
foreach my $payer ( @{ $our_payments{$id}{'payers'} } ) {
    print "Adding ", $vendor_payments{$last_name}{$payer}{'total'},
        " to vendor total $vendor_total.\n";

    $vendor_total += $vendor_payments{$last_name}{$payer}{'total'};
}
        
print "\nVendor total: $vendor_total\n";
print "Our total: $our_total\n";
            
if ($our_total == $vendor_total) {
    print "Yay! They match!\n";
}
else {
    print "Boo! They don't match!\n";
}
```

And here's the relevant output:

```
hash total: -25856.73

our total: 25856.73
Adding 25856.73 to vendor total 0.

Vendor total: 25856.73
Our total: 25856.73
Boo! They don't match!
```

The only thing I can think of is that their might be some weird encoding problem with the files (there's accent symbols on names in one of them) but I don't see how that would affect the strings being converted to numbers.

I thought that by outputting the data to screen, I'd be able to see what's going on, but the numbers look exactly the same to me, and I'm running into this issue with multiple "matching" numbers, so I know there's something programmatically wrong.

Comment: "Floating point" and printing... try this: `perl -wE'$x = 1.73; $y = 1.730000000000001; say $x; say $y; if ($x == $y) { say "equal" }'`  They are printed the same (with one zero fewer they _are not_) but fail `==`.  One of your `25856.73` has extra digits far far down

Comment: I looked at the original file that $our_total was read from, and it shows up in Notepad++ as being UTF-16 LE BOM. I saved it as UTF-8 (like the other file) but I still seem to have weird issues with the numeric comparisons.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think this was an issue, because I was reading in payment values and wasn't dealing with miniscule fractions of numbers, and only adding dollars and cents. 

I didn't think I could be got by weird floating point problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Right, but it's just about how (floating point) numbers are represented internally.  It's probably good to switch to integers if it makes sense in your applications (cents if it's moneys) but still watch those places where you'll have to convert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %our_payments = (
    one => {total  => '12.1',
            payers => [qw[ x y ]]}
);
my %vendor_payments = (
    last => {x => {total => 9.9 },
             y => {total => 2.2 }}
);
my $last_name = 'last';
my $id = 'one';

my $vendor_total = 0;

print "hash total: ", $our_payments{$id}{'total'}, "\n\n";

my $our_total = abs($our_payments{$id}{'total'});
print "our total: $our_total\n";

foreach my $payer ( @{ $our_payments{$id}{'payers'} } ) {
    print "Adding ", $vendor_payments{$last_name}{$payer}{'total'},
        " to vendor total $vendor_total.\n";

    $vendor_total += $vendor_payments{$last_name}{$payer}{'total'};
}

printf "\nVendor total: %.20f\n", $vendor_total;
printf "Our total: %.20f\n", $our_total;

if ($our_total == $vendor_total) {
    print "Yay! They match!\n";
}
else {
    print "Boo! They don't match!\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hash total: 12.1

our total: 12.1
Adding 9.9 to vendor total 0.
Adding 2.2 to vendor total 9.9.

Vendor total: 12.10000000000000142109
Our total: 12.09999999999999964473
Boo! They don't match!
```

To fix the problem, don't use `==`, but rather something like

```perl
if (abs($our_total - $vendor_total) < 1E-10) {
```

or

```perl
if (sprintf('%.10f', $our_total) eq sprintf('%.10f', $vendor_total)) {
```

Comment: It's so weird because I'm reading in what are basically payments - and I've never seen issues like this when only dealing with tenths and hundredths.

I'm wondering if I should just convert everything to cents and use integers. :D

Thanks - it was an issue I didn't even think of.

Comment: I always say that writing `$x == $y` for floats is in principle a programming error

Comment: Converting to the smallest currency unit (cents, pence, etc) and using integer maths is a very common approach.